# Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio-2.0

When I build the project,gradle show me many errors like this below:
[error pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbGSe.png)

I have search many solutions,but no one is the right solution.

For example,add "-keepattributes EnclosingMethod", add "-keepattributes InnerClasses"……

I use the 2.0 version of Android Studio,is the new version got the error?

Hope for helps,thanks

UPDATE:

Error Logs:

```
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(com.baidu.location.BDLocation$1) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
```

Comment: add build.gradle file here.